# Spring Data Neo4j Expected a result with a single record, but this result contains at least one more. Ensure your query returns only one record

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-driver

I develop an event meeting application using Spring and Neo4j database.

This is my model:

Member can Create Event and other member can register and check in event when member who is organizer has start check in event.

[image: Event models]

This is my entities in java code

**Event Entity**

```java
@Node
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String type;

    private Long startDate;

    private Long endDate;

    private String location;

    private String coverImageUrl;

    private List<String> postImageUrls;

    private Integer numberOfPeople;

    private String status;

    private String checkInCode;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Long updateAt;

    @CreatedDate
    private Long createAt;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Relationship(type = "TAG", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private List<Tag> tags;

    @Relationship(type = "CREATE", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Member organizer;


    @Relationship(type = "FEEDBACK", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<FeedbackFromRelation> feedbackEvent;

    @Relationship(type = "CHECK_IN",direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<CheckInEventFromRelation> checkInMember;

    @Relationship(type = "REGISTER", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<RegisterEventFromRelation> registerMember;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Event event = (Event) o;

        return id.equals(event.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

**Member Entity**

```java
@Node
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Member {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String username;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String profileUrl;

    private String deviceId;

    private String email;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Long updateAt;

    @CreatedDate
    private Long createAt;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Relationship(value = "CREATE",direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Event> createdEvent;

    @Relationship(type = "FOLLOW", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Member> follower;

    @Relationship(type = "REGISTER", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<RegisterEventRelation> registerEvent;

    @Relationship(type = "CHECK_IN",direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<CheckInEventRelation> checkInEvent;

    @Relationship(type = "FEEDBACK",direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<FeedbackRelation> feedbackEvent;

    public Member(String id, String firstname, String lastname, String image, String email,String deviceId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.profileUrl = image;
        this.email = email;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Member member = (Member) o;

        return id.equals(member.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

This is my service I try to execute in that time. It throw the exception when I try to save that event.

```java
    public String generateCode(String memberId, String eventId) throws MemberNotFoundException, EventNotFoundException, NotHavePermissionException {
        Member owner = memberService.getMember(memberId);
        Event event = getEventById(eventId);
        if (event.getOrganizer().getId().equals(owner.getId())) {
            String code = randomCode();
            event.setCheckInCode(code);
            save(event);
            log.info("generate code {} for eventId {} ", code, eventId);
            return code;
        }
        throw new NotHavePermissionException(String.format("MemberId %s is not owner", memberId));
    }
```

And this is sample data in database

[image: sample-data]

I face up with this **exception**. I have no idea what exception that is. I just try to save entity. Could you give me advice about this exception ?

ps. Is it related to when i get event, it load too many entity ?

```java
2022-07-21 23:58:08.582  WARN 10601 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .n.c.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator : Don't know how to translate exception of type class org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.NoSuchRecordException
2022-07-21 23:58:08.723 ERROR 10601 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/eventService] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.NoSuchRecordException: Expected a result with a single record, but this result contains at least one more. Ensure your query returns only one record.] with root cause

org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.NoSuchRecordException: Expected a result with a single record, but this result contains at least one more. Ensure your query returns only one record.
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:144) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5-27f38b532a360cf35485df12ced05e31409afcd3]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.blockingGet(InternalResult.java:122) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5-27f38b532a360cf35485df12ced05e31409afcd3]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.single(InternalResult.java:75) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5-27f38b532a360cf35485df12ced05e31409afcd3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient$DefaultRecordFetchSpec.one(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:455) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.saveRelatedNode(Neo4jTemplate.java:882) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:788) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.lambda$processNestedRelations$25(Neo4jTemplate.java:842) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:387) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:697) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.processRelations(Neo4jTemplate.java:682) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.saveImpl(Neo4jTemplate.java:421) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:343) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SimpleNeo4jRepository.save(SimpleNeo4jRepository.java:119) ~[spring-data-neo4j-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.eventloop.eventservice.services.EventService.save(EventService.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.eventloop.eventservice.services.EventService.generateCode(EventService.java:228) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.eventloop.eventservice.services.EventService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$88140695.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.eventloop.eventservice.services.EventService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a417af2.generateCode(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.eventloop.eventservice.controllers.EventController.generateCode(EventController.java:95) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil$InternalExceptionCause: null
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.cursor.AsyncResultCursorImpl.lambda$null$0(AsyncResultCursorImpl.java:85) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5-27f38b532a360cf35485df12ced05e31409afcd3]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyNow(CompletableFuture.java:680) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:658) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:2094) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:143) ~[na:na]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.cursor.AsyncResultCursorImpl.lambda$singleAsync$1(AsyncResultCursorImpl.java:81) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5-27f38b532a360cf35485df12ced05e31409afcd3]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:143) ~[na:na]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.cursor.AsyncResultCursorImpl.singleAsync(AsyncResultCursorImpl.java:74) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5-27f38b532a360cf35485df12ced05e31409afcd3]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.cursor.DisposableAsyncResultCursor.lambda$singleAsync$2(DisposableAsyncResultCursor.java:72) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5-27f38b532a360cf35485df12ced05e31409afcd3]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235) ~[na:na]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.cursor.DisposableAsyncResultCursor.singleAsync(DisposableAsyncResultCursor.java:72) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5-27f38b532a360cf35485df12ced05e31409afcd3]
        ... 139 common frames omitted
```

**Update**

I add **Save** method that actually it do

```
    public Event save(Event event) {
        eventRepository.save(event);
        log.info("save event : {} ", event.getId());
        return event;
    }
```

Comment: did you got the solution.I am also facing same issue

Comment: @rafeek I resolved this problems. This cause by models id is not unique key (I use name of tag model to be unique) so i let spring to generate uuid for each node follow my issues
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2573

Answer (score 0):

The error says,

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.NoSuchRecordException: Expected a result with a single record, but this result contains at least one more. Ensure your query returns only one record.
```

This implies your query returns more than one record as the return value, but it is expected to return only one record. Try executing the query directly on `Neo4j Browser`, to see what is the return value from the query.

Comment: I'm not sure which cypher query do it for me. I use Spring Data Neo4j to save entity


I have try with this query it return only one record 

`match (e:Event{id:'5d5864c4-36d3-4d12-a36a-599d456d98b1'})
set e.checkInCode = '456789'
return e
`

Comment: In the stack trace the query method name will be there

Comment: I only found the exception has started when i execute `eventRepository.save(event)`.  

Do you have another method to make query log from spring ? 

I have try  `logging.level.org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest=DEBUG
` there noting print out

Comment: I have try to reduce relation between event node it not throw the exception but it take long time to save entity

[Before reduce relation](https://imgur.com/a/FQA8XtN)


[After reduce relation](https://imgur.com/a/1xaqeJF)

Answer (score 0):

To print the Logs, use;

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.neo4j=DEBUG
```

For unique IDs;

```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generatorClass = UUIDStringGenerator.class)
   private long id;
```